# How to emulate elastic beanstalk environment locally for developers without docker?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a php/laravel application on elastic beanstalk with RDS,
I'm not using Docker for that.
How can I emulate the beanstalk application for developers to be the same environment on AWS without using docker ??

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21474197/457268

Comment: What's your requirement? Why don't you want to use docker and which other technologies do you deem useable on your local stack?

Comment: The production and test servers are already up and running using beanstalk, If docker is the only option, I would have to rebuild the entire thing from scratch and deploy a new app on beanstalk with docker.
I'm asking if something like EB CLI can do the job without using docker